# Get meta data attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I am having trouble retrieving information from a meta tag.  I am trying to get an img src from a website and can't quite figure it out.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://foo.jpg">
var image = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]').getAttribute('content');
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: `<meta>` is an element, `property` is an attribute. you'd want something more like `meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')`, scan through that for your og:image attribute, then get the associated content.

Answer (score 24):

`meta` elements aren't special, you can query for them and get their attributes in the normal way.

In this case, here's how you'd get the `content` attribute value from the first `meta[property="og:image"]` element:

```
var element = document.querySelector('meta[property~="og:image"]');
var content = element && element.getAttribute("content");
```

`querySelector` is supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Note that the `content` property is also available as a reflected property, so you can just use `.content` rather than `.getAttribute("content")`:

```
var element = document.querySelector('meta[property~="og:image"]');
var content = element && element.content;
```

In modern JavaScript you can use the optional chaining operator (`?.`) to combine those two statements:

```
const content = document.querySelector('meta[property~="og:image"]')?.content;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

If the element isn't found, `content` will get the value `undefined`; otherwise, it'll get the value of the reflected property (which is the attribute value).