# Retriving the content of meta tag by language in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This question is not a duplicate of [Get meta data attribute in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124579/get-meta-data-attribute-in-javascript). I'd like to get `meta name` by **language**.

I have the following in HTML code:

```
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="pl" content="wróg" />
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="en" content="enemy" />
```

There are also other `meta name` tags in HTML.

It is quite easy to get the content of the first `DC.Subject`by using:

`document.getElementsByName("DC.Description")[0].getAttribute("content"))`

and the second by

`document.getElementsByName("DC.Description")[1].getAttribute("content"))`

But this is not **language specific**. However, how do I get the content of `DC.Description` by using `xml:lang=` in **JavaScript**?

Comment: Take a look at this question, I think it's the same as the one you're asking - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949341/how-to-obtain-lang-attribute-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get meta data attribute in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124579/get-meta-data-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: @LGSon Your post does not explain how to get attribute by *language*.

Comment: I see that now .. was too quick ... but this one does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034283/is-it-possible-to-use-htmls-queryselector-to-select-by-xlink-attribute-in-an

Comment: @RoseRobertson I do not want to obtain the declared language of the document.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `document.querySelector` as follows:

```js
var plMeta = document.querySelector('[xml\\:lang="pl"][name="DC.Subject"]');

console.log(plMeta);
```

```html
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="pl" content="wróg">
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="en" content="enemy">
```

Here's a related Q&A to get more in touch with CSS selectors involving namespaces: [Is it possible to use HTML's .querySelector() to select by xlink attribute in an SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034283/is-it-possible-to-use-htmls-queryselector-to-select-by-xlink-attribute-in-an)

Comment: It's a dupe so please close it as such

Comment: @LGSon I believe OP's issue isn't getting a `<meta>` but getting it by `xml:lang` which involves escaping `:`

Comment: `Error: {
  "message": "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 64
}`

Comment: @connexo I hope you didn't downvote my answer because of an extra parenthesis :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer You are right. I do not want just to get `<meta>` (my post shows I can do it). I'd like to know how to get it by `xml:lang` However, in the webpage there are more than one `meta` with `xml:lang`. How do I get `<meta name="DC.Subject"` (there are other `<meta name`) by language?

Comment: @menteith You combine the attributes: `document.querySelector('[name="DC.Subject"][xml\\:lang="pl"]');`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, the linked one would work well to close this question as a dupe ... better than the one suggested as I were a little too quick :)

Comment: @menteith I've updated my answer to meet this requirement too.

Comment: @menteith Can there be more than one element you want to catch?

Comment: @LGSon There could be several `meta name="DC.Subject"`  and also several `xml:lang="pl"` and other `meta name=` if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: @menteith Well then you will need `document.querySelectorAll` instead, and loop through the array of object

Comment: Which is what my answer does.

Comment: @menteith I believe that you've enough info to solve the rest of your requirements yourself :) it's all about combining CSS selectors. It would be a bad idea to turn answer into the CSS selector bible :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the problematic `:` character in the attribute name:

```js
var xml_lang_elements = document.querySelectorAll('[xml\\:lang][name="DC.Subject"]');
for (var i = 0; i < xml_lang_elements.length; i++) { 
  console.log(xml_lang_elements[i].getAttribute('content'));
}
```

```html
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="pl" content="wróg" />
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="en" content="enemy" />
```